# JIS 0201 encoded SAM file conversion to decoded text file

Tags: shift-jis

How can I convert JIS 0201 encoded SAM file to decoded text file. Currently I dont have much information and I am figure out how to proceed on this. Please help.

jis 0201 encoded SAM file conversion to decoded text file using java.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.